# AuthenticationError: invalid signature coinbase nodejs

Tags: node.js, coinbase-api

Here is my code wanna create a new addresss using nodejs :

```
    var Client = require('coinbase').Client;

    var client = new Client({
        'apiKey': 'myApiKey',
        'apiSecret': 'myApiSecret'
      });

    console.log(client)
    var address = null;

    client.getAccount('primary', function(err, account) {
        account.createAddress(function(err, addr) {
            console.log(addr);
            address = addr;
        });
        console.log(err)
    });
```

But i'm getting AuthenticationError: invalid signature !
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API key I created had not the required permissions !
I just needed to create a new one with required permissions !